# Communityがタグを作成する時はどんなとき？

Tags: サポート, タグ

[ubuntuタグ](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/tags/ubuntu/info)は[Communityユーザー](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/revisions/25440/1)が作成したことになっています。
そこで質問なのですがCommunityがタグを作成する時はどんなときでしょうか。よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: マルチポスト:[Meta Stack Exchange](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/284881/when-does-the-community-user-create-a-tag)

Comment: 作成したことになっている、というのはタグのwikiやwiki抜粋の事ですね。そうだとすると、ユーザが新しく作成した際に、元になる空のバージョンがあった事にするために、過去に遡ってCommunityユーザーが作成した履歴が作られている気がします。

Comment: すでに質問されていたみたい…(重複でクローズ)

Comment: Communityが初版の投稿者になっていない場合もある（例えば[c](http://ja.stackoverflow.com/posts/2185/revisions)）のは、レビューなしで編集できる人が作成した場合なんですかね。

Comment: @mjy タグwikiです。(実は作成日時の横に"ユーザー名によって"とつく時とつかないときの基準も気になっています)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Meta Stack Exchangeで質問した結果、次のような質問を見つけました。
[Community user "stealing" tags?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/108319/community-user-stealing-tags) (Communityユーザーはタグを"盗む"？)
その[回答](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/108321/332584)の一部を日本語に訳して引用します。

> タグの作成者はタグwikiの作成者ではありません。それは作成者が初めて質問に使っただけです。
>   (誰が作成者か表示しろという機能要求がある)
>   ある程度の信用度で、タグのwikiの編集を提案することができます。
>   タグwikiが作成されていない場合は、Communityが代わりに作成します。